# stop django from automatically unicodifing POST stuff

Tags: django, unicode

I upload some data to a django view. Client:

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode

def upload_data(upload_url, data, filename):
    print "Uploading %d bytes to server, file=%s..." % (len(data), filename)

    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({filename: data})

    request = urllib2.Request(upload_url, datagen, headers)
    # Actually do the request, and get the response
    try:
        resp_f = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=120)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        return None

    res = resp_f.read()
    resp_f.close()
    return res

#...

def foo(self, event_dicts_td):
    event_dicts_td_json = json.dumps(event_dicts_td)
    res = upload_data(self.upload_url, event_dicts_td_json.encode('utf8').encode('zlib'), "event_dicts_td.json.gz")
```

The view:

```
def my_view(request):
    event_dicts_td_json_gz = request.POST.get('event_dicts_td.json.gz')
    if not event_dicts_td_json_gz:
        return HttpResponse("fail")

    print type(event_dicts_td_json_gz), repr(event_dicts_td_json_gz[:10])
    event_dicts_td_json_gz = event_dicts_td_json_gz.encode("utf8")
    print type(event_dicts_td_json_gz), repr(event_dicts_td_json_gz[:10])

    event_dicts_td_json = event_dicts_td_json_gz.decode("zlib").decode("utf8")

    return HttpResponse("it still failed")
```

The output:

```
<type 'unicode'> u'x\ufffd\ufffd]s\ufffd\u0192\ufffd\ufffd\n'
<type 'str'> 'x\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd]s\xef'
```

This is not acceptable. I just need the **raw** bytes. I'm not uploading unicode - I'm uploading raw bytes - and I want those raw bytes back. I don't know how it's trying to decode it into unicode - apparently not using `utf8` cause zlib was unable to decompress the data. (It was unable to decompress it even when I didn't try to do an `.encode("utf8")` before zlibbing-it, that was just a test.)

How do I make django not unicodify the POST variables? Or, if it does, how do I undo it?

Comment: Do you need the bytes as string or list of numbers? What is unacceptable - <type 'unicode'>, <type 'str'> or both?

Comment: @sergzach: it's unacceptable that it is somehow decoding a string of bytes into a unicode string. i'm passing it raw bytes, NOT strings. i want the raw bytes back, not raw bytes decoded into a unicode string.

Comment: Could you specify the full view function with the declaration and the necessary imports please?

Comment: @sergzach: i updated it to make it a working function, but wasn't much more to see than that

Answer (score 0):

You can undo this.

Try to use *smart_str* from **django.utils.encoding**:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str    
event_dicts_td_json_gz = smart_str( event_dicts_td_json_gz )
```

View the docs here please: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#useful-utility-functions

Comment: No, I don't want my data in a readable format - I want the data _as it is uploaded_ - the raw bytes. I upload raw bytes from one end and get unicode at the other. Something is wrong with that picture.